# How do you disable hardware-accelerated GPU scheduling via the command line in Windows 10/11?

Tags: windows, windows-registry, gpu

I need to disable, programmatically, hardware-accelerated GPU scheduling in Windows if it's enabled.

[image: UI settings for HW-accelerated GPU scheduling]

Searching, I was pointed at the `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\GraphicsDrivers` - `HwSchMode` regkey.  This is `2` when HW GPU scheduling is enabled and `1` after disabling via the settings UI.

I've tried just setting this regkey to 1 and rebooting, but while this key remains changed after reboot, HW accelerated GPU scheduling is still enabled.

Is there any other method to disable this that isn't the UI?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I was using `REG_SZ` instead of `REG_DWORD` when setting the value.  Once I changed my code to use this instead, everything started working as expected.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\GraphicsDrivers]
"HwSchMode"=dword:00000001
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this setting.  It is dated Dec 2021, so not tool old.  It is implying that you create this entry.

```
KeyPath   : HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\GraphicsDrivers\Scheduler
KeyValue  : EnablePreemption
ValueType : REG_DWORD
ValueData : 0 to disable preemption, 1 to enable preemption (default).
```

> To help in debugging the driver, the behavior of the graphics processing unit (GPU) scheduler can be changed by configuring the registry.
>
> You can enable or disable preemption requests from the GPU scheduler (see Timeout Detection and Recovery) by using the following registry configuration:

From **learn.microsoft**  [Changing the Behavior of the GPU Scheduler for Debugging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/display/changing-the-behavior-of-the-gpu-scheduler-for-debugging)

Comment: I was just setting the wrong data type for the reg key.  It needed to be a dword instead of string.