# Hardware-accelerated GPU scheduling option missing - Windows 10 LTSC

Tags: windows-10, drivers, graphics-card, gpu

I need to enable hardware-accelerated GPU scheduling. (Specifically because the settings window on the splash screen of the videogame Darktide says it’s not.) However, Windows doesn’t list that option where it’s supposed to be: `Settings > System > Display > Graphics Settings`

I tried updating my 526.47 Nvidia drivers to the latest version: 531.18. I used NVCleanstall 1.15.1, installing the following driver components: Display Diver, PhysX. Additional NVCleanstall installation tweaks: `‘Disable Installer Telemetry & Advertising’, ‘Perform a Clean Installation’, ‘Enable DLSS Indicator’`. Followed by a reboot.

Based on [this article](https://superuser.com/questions/1765375/how-do-you-disable-hardware-accelerated-gpu-scheduling-via-the-command-line-in-w), I tried adding a DWORD value named `HwSchMode` to the registry under `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\GraphicsDrivers`, with a value of 2, followed by a reboot.

No dice in both cases.

Graphics card: Asus RTX 3808 (TUF-RTX3080-O10G-V2-GAMING)

Windows version: Windows 10 Enterprise N LTSC, version 1809, build 17763.4010

Comment: That feature was introduced in Windows 10 version 2004 - 1809 is too early

Answer (score 0):

As [JaromandaX](https://superuser.com/users/504075/jaromanda-x) pointed out, the Windows version I'm on is too old. (Which I apparently got wrong prior to posting this question.) Thank you!

(To clarify further, Windows LTSC does not receive feature updates.)